# Can I run an instance of python with a script saved as a variable

Tags: python, shell, instance

Can I run a separate instance of python that runs a script that is saved as a variable

main.py

```
script = "print('hello')"
```

What would I have to add to main.py to make it run another instance of python with it running the variable 'script'

Comment: I guess the first question I have would be to understand why you would want to do this. Normally when this kind of thing comes up its because you want to do something else and normally there is an easier way to do that something else

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I'm trying to make a simple chat room script in python for my school task. however, command prompt and most of internet is blocked so I cannot install any graphical libraries. Due to this I need two Separate windows, one for sending messages and the other for receiving.